# Building a crawler to get the content of page

Tags: c#, html, http, httpwebrequest

I'm writing one crawler to get the content of the website, however I have some doubts as following :

1. one URL which is debugged by Fiddler, in which I need to set some values ( set/get the sessionID, put in the dates...) in this URL with get parameters.
2. then I have another POST URL which uses the cookie which is contained in above URL in order to produce the content of the page with the date given above.

In C# what I did was, first I run the first URL to parse the ID , second I set the ID get the Session ID (PHPSESSID) , the third step I give the parameters with dates, Fourth, I run the final URL to get the content, but in the last step, it warns me that the date input format might not be correct, and I tried many date format types but still no results.

Is there any relation between those URLs as I did them separatedly, in order to get the content of the page ? I use the same PHPSESSID for each HTTPWebRequest

Comment: A simple crawler wouldn't use http POST for information retrieval. You'd only want to handle GET requests due to numerous reasons: it's safe, it's meant to retrieve data, it's idempotent, it doesn't modify server state...

Comment: @oleksii Yes when I debug the page with Fiddler, I could see many requests are executed before receiving the content of the page, I would like to simulate them in C# just like those steps but it seems like I still dont get the ideas of how each request is related to each other.

Comment: And I need to use some obligatory information, I have to use HTTP POST with given values, both GET and POST